# scale text in eww with proportional fonts enabled

Tags: fonts, eww, scaling, variable-pitch, zooming

when i use eww, which is v often, coz i love reading the web by just text in a format i choose,

i can scale the text (with `C-x +/-`) until i enable "proportional fonts" with `F`. it changes my display text to be the same as my settings for `variable-pitch-mode`, but when enabled the text doesn't scale (although some other objects do).

scaling works fine in other buffers that have `variable-pitch-mode` enabled.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem starting from `emacs -Q`? If so, please report bugs via `M-x report-emacs-bug RET`. Please also provide more details, with step-by-step descriptions, as I am unable to reproduce the issue given the information you have provided.

Comment: Please consider editing your question, to use ordinary sentences: capitalization, no abbreviations, etc.

Comment: @Basil running `emacs -Q` the text scales fine with proportional fonts on, so it's not emacs it's me. happy to provide more details, but i'm not sure what? it's helpful already to know that it works for you.

Comment: @mooseface If something works under `emacs -Q` but not under your config, then you should try to narrow down which part of your config gives rise to the problem, e.g. by commenting-out different parts of it. If the issue lies with code you've written, then you can try to fix it. Otherwise, you should provide a minimal recipe for reproducing the issue starting from `emacs -Q` with step-by-step descriptions of what you type, execute, see, expect, etc. Without this information it's very hard for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in my case, scaling didn't work because my variable-pitch configuration specified the `:height` in the format `140`. i switched it to the format `1.3`. and now it works.

(thanks Basil for the pointers. `emacs -Q` will come in handy again i'm sure.)