# How to set heading and TODO fonts?

Tags: org-mode, faces, fonts

I use spacemacs theme on Emacs 28.2.

My config for faces is:

```lisp
  (custom-theme-set-faces                                          
   'user                                                           
   '(variable-pitch ((t (:family "ETbb" :height 180))))            
   '(fixed-pitch ((t ( :family "Fira Code Retina" :height 160))))
   (set-face-attribute 'org-table nil  :inherit 'fixed-pitch)
   ) 
  (add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'variable-pitch-mode)
```

And

```lisp
  (custom-theme-set-faces                                                       
    'user                                                                       
    '(org-block ((t (:inherit fixed-pitch))))                                   
    '(org-code ((t (:family "DejaVu Sans Mono"))))
    '(org-document-info-keyword ((t (:inherit (shadow fixed-pitch)))))          
    '(org-meta-line ((t (:inherit (font-lock-comment-face fixed-pitch)))))      
    '(org-property-value ((t (:inherit fixed-pitch))) t)                        
    '(org-special-keyword ((t (:inherit (font-lock-comment-face fixed-pitch)))))
    '(org-tag ((t (:inherit (shadow fixed-pitch) :weight bold :height 0.8))))
    '(org-table ((t (:family "DejaVu Sans Mono" :foreground "#83a598"))))
    '(org-verbatim ((t (:inherit (shadow fixed-pitch))))))
```

In order to set headings and TODO fonts I added this to the last code block:

```lisp
'(org-todo ((t (:font "DejaVu Sans Mono"))))
'(org-level-1 ((t (:font "Gillius ADF"))))
```

The result is that

- `org-level-1` has `Gillius ADF` but size doesn't change when doing `text-scale-increase`/`text-scale-decrease`.
- `org-todo` has `ETbb` font instead of `DejaVu Sans Mono`

Hence my question: how to set the heading and TODO fonts?

EDIT (additional information):

- `describe-face` > `org-todo` gives:

```
Face: org-todo (sample) (customize this face)

Documentation:
Face for TODO keywords.

Defined in ‘org-faces.el’.


           Family: DejaVu Sans Mono
          Foundry: PfEd
            Width: normal
           Height: 113
           Weight: normal
            Slant: normal
       Foreground: #dc752f
DistantForeground: unspecified
       Background: #f6f1e1
        Underline: unspecified
         Overline: unspecified
   Strike-through: unspecified
              Box: unspecified
          Inverse: unspecified
          Stipple: unspecified
             Font: #<font-object -PfEd-DejaVu Sans Mono-normal-normal-normal-*-15-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1>
          Fontset: unspecified
           Extend: unspecified
          Inherit: bold
```

- `C-u C-x =` on TODO gives:

```
             position: 5 of 21475 (0%), column: 4
            character: X (displayed as X) (codepoint 88, #o130, #x58)
              charset: ascii (ASCII (ISO646 IRV))
code point in charset: 0x58
               script: latin
               syntax: w    which means: word
             category: .:Base, L:Strong L2R, a:ASCII, l:Latin, r:Roman
             to input: type "C-x 8 RET 58" or "C-x 8 RET LATIN CAPITAL LETTER X"
          buffer code: #x58
            file code: #x58 (encoded by coding system utf-8-unix)
              display: by this font (glyph code):
    ftcrhb:-PfEd-ETbb-bold-normal-normal-*-24-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1 (#x39)

Character code properties: customize what to show
  name: LATIN CAPITAL LETTER X
  general-category: Lu (Letter, Uppercase)
  decomposition: (88) ('X')

There are text properties here:
  face                 (:foreground "#af00ec" :background "FF" :bold t :weight bold)
  fontified            t
```

- `describe-face` > `org-level-1` gives

```
Documentation:
Face used for level 1 headlines.

Defined in ‘org-faces.el’.


           Family: Gillius ADF
          Foundry: ADFP
            Width: normal
           Height: 113
           Weight: bold
            Slant: normal
       Foreground: #3a81c3
DistantForeground: unspecified
       Background: unspecified
        Underline: unspecified
         Overline: unspecified
   Strike-through: unspecified
              Box: unspecified
          Inverse: unspecified
          Stipple: unspecified
             Font: #<font-object -ADFP-Gillius ADF-bold-normal-normal-*-15-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1>
          Fontset: unspecified
           Extend: nil
          Inherit: bold
```

- `C-u C-x =` on Level 1 Headline gives:

```
               position: 20579 of 21475 (96%), column: 9
            character: i (displayed as i) (codepoint 105, #o151, #x69)
              charset: ascii (ASCII (ISO646 IRV))
code point in charset: 0x69
               script: latin
               syntax: w    which means: word
             category: .:Base, L:Strong L2R, a:ASCII, l:Latin, r:Roman
             to input: type "C-x 8 RET 69" or "C-x 8 RET LATIN SMALL LETTER I"
          buffer code: #x69
            file code: #x69 (encoded by coding system utf-8-unix)
              display: by this font (glyph code):
    ftcrhb:-ADFP-Gillius ADF-bold-normal-normal-*-15-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1 (#x4A)

Character code properties: customize what to show
  name: LATIN SMALL LETTER I
  general-category: Ll (Letter, Lowercase)
  decomposition: (105) ('i')

There are text properties here:
  face                 org-level-1
  fontified            t
```

Comment: Use `describe-face` to figure out how each face is defined and what it inherits from. Use `C-u C-x =` on a character in the buffer to find out its face. It will take some fumbling to figure out what's going on.

Comment: I edited the question to add the command you mentioned. I noticed another issue (maybe I should open a new question): Everything that is not `variable-pitch`  is not affected by `text-scale-increase`/`text-scale-decrease`.

Comment: Yes, you probably should add a new question if that is the case.

Comment: I managed to solve this issue by changing `fixed-pitch` value from `160` to `0.8` (found the solution [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/56005/scale-text-in-eww-with-proportional-fonts-enabled)). It didn't solve the heading and TODO issue though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Instead of `:font`, use `:family`
2. Instead of using `custom-theme-set-faces` to set TODO font, use `org-todo-keyword-faces`.

   Example:

   ```lisp
   (setq org-todo-keyword-faces '(
                    ("BACKLOG" . (:family "DejaVu Sans Mono" :foreground "#ae81ff" :background "FF" :bold t :weight bold))
                    ("NEXT" . (:family "DejaVu Sans Mono" :foreground "#af00ec" :background "FF" :bold t :weight bold))
                    ("MEETING" . (:family "DejaVu Sans Mono" :foreground "#00ffc0" :background "FF" :bold t :weight bold)) 
                    ("STARTED" . (:family "DejaVu Sans Mono" :foreground "#ff84c9" :background "FF" :bold t :weight bold))
                    ("WAITING" . (:family "DejaVu Sans Mono" :foreground "#fbd814" :background "FF" :bold t :weight bold))
                    ("DELEGATED" . (:family "DejaVu Sans Mono" :foreground "#fc5155" :background "FF" :bold t :weight bold))
                    ("DONE" . (:family "DejaVu Sans Mono" :foreground "gray65" :background "FF" :bold t :weight bold))
                    ("DEFERRED" . ( :family "DejaVu Sans Mono":foreground "#4577d7" :background "FF" :bold t :weight bold))
                    ("CANCELLED" . (:family "DejaVu Sans Mono" :foreground "gray40" :background "FF" :bold t :weight bold))
                    )
   )
   ```